# Enriching Table

Tags: sql, teradata

This is my query:

```
 SELECT 
 a.account_type AS ACCOUNT_TYPE
,b.at_account_type_desc
,COUNT(a.BAN) AS num_BAN 
 FROM csm_adx.billing_account_act AS a 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN csm_adx.account_type_act AS b ON a.account_type = b.at_acc_type
 GROUP BY 1,2
```

Now I want to connect it to another table TABLE_C which contains the information is the account: tentative, cancelled, closed, suspended, open.

I would like my result table to contain aditional three columns: `ACTIVE_BAN`, `SUSPENDED_BAN` and `CANCELLED_BAN`
and that each value contains the number of current active, suspended and cancelled bans. I´m using Teradata.

Can you please help me do this?

This is the result when the table is connected with another table which contains BAN status:

```
SELECT 
 a.account_type AS ACCOUNT_TYPE
,b.at_account_type_desc
,c.description
,COUNT(a.BAN) AS num_BAN
FROM csm_adx.billing_account_act AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN csm_adx.account_type_act AS b 
ON a.account_type = b.at_acc_type
LEFT OUTER JOIN csm_adx.acct_status AS c
ON a.ban_status = c.original_status_code
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 a.account_type AS ACCOUNT_TYPE
,b.at_account_type_desc
,COUNT(a.BAN) AS num_BAN ,
 sum(case when a.column=value then 1 else 0 end) as 'user_colname1',
sum(case when b.column=value then 1 else 0 end) as 'user_colname2'
 FROM csm_adx.billing_account_act AS a 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN csm_adx.account_type_act AS b 
ON a.account_type = b.at_acc_type
 GROUP BY 1,2
```